# Gerrit- Unable to create users in gerrit code review web UI

Tags: gerrit

getting following error -Code Review - Error The page you requested was not found, or you do not have permission to view this page. But i have logged in as admin privilege.

`server {

```
   listen       81 default_server;
    listen       [::]:81 default_server;
    server_name  192.168.1.34;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location  / {
    auth_basic "Basic Auth";
    auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
    proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.34:8081";
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header  Host $host;

    }

}

gerrit config is 



   [gerrit]
        basePath = git
       serverId = f40260b7-33a9-45da-80e1-2336d844d0d3
       canonicalWebUrl = http://192.168.1.34:8081/gerrit
  [database]
    type = mysql
    hostname = 192.168.1.34
    database = reviewdb
    username = gerrit
 [index]
        type = LUCENE
     [auth]
          type = HTTP
    [receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
    [sendemail]
    smtpServer = 192.168.1.32
    smtpServerPort = 465
    smtpEncryption = SSL
    smtpUser = shiva.k@modefinserver.com
  [container]
     user = mfsadm
     javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-
                        0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre
                [sshd]
                  listenAddress = *:29418
                  [httpd]
               listenUrl = proxy-http://*:8081/
                    [cache]
        directory = cache
```

these are my configurations.

Comment: Please provide more details about your config and when this error happens.

Comment: my nginx config s  server {
       listen       81 default_server;
        listen       [::]:81 default_server;
        server_name  192.xx.x.xx;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location  / {
        auth_basic "Basic Auth";
        auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
        proxy_pass "http://192.xxx.1.xx:8081/";
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  Host $host;

        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

Comment: i am getting when i want to add users to group

Comment: I have deleted my answer about `AllowEncodedSlashes`, which is kind of a frequent mistake (happening when you open issue details). Based the information you provided now, this seems not to be the case for you.

Comment: Please edit your post and include your configuration. Thanks. Please check the `logs/error_log` file for any information.

Comment: error.log says  [HTTP-73] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.container.HttpLoginServlet : Unable to authenticate user by Authorization request header.  Check container or server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using http as auth type. we need to add users by command line.

cat ~/.ssh/id_watcher.pub | ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit create-account --group "'Non-Interactive Users'" --ssh-key - watcher